# Is it possible to prevent people with cracked copies of the game from joining my server?

Tags: terraria

I want to start an open Terraria server, and would like to keep players running cracked clients off of my server.

Is there any way that I can accomplish this? I am using the Steam version, if it makes any difference.

Comment: Hmmm i'm almost sure cracked versions can play on cracked servers. But i'm not sure if they can play on legal servers. Mostly the cracked games will be a version behind the legal ones, so if you have the latest version and the crack is 1 lower then they can't join. But I really don't know when it was the last time terraria was updated so it could still be the same.

Comment: Well, the 1.1.2 version has been around for more than a year now, I am pretty sure it is available as cracked. But thanks for the input on this!

Comment: I am not sure if it would be possible to determine whether a copy of the game is cracked.

Comment: @Lyrion: what you say does hold true for Minecraft, at least at the time of writing.

Comment: @oKtosiTe I know a friend who wanted to play it but didn't want to pay for it before trying it first had an illegal copy and I couldn't play with him, because at that time the steam version was 1 version ahead. So I had to download it just so I could play with him. But that was ages ago tho :p

Comment: Im pretty sure that steam is what backs up your account authentication so maybye if there was a way you could make your server check if they have steam but idk what would do that or if it would count as hacking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up testing this myself.

Unfortunately, illegal copies of the game can access my server.

Upon examining packets received by server with [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) I found nothing that would indicate difference between a cracked client and my steam copy.

Since there is no way to distinguish this, there would be no way for only legal owners of game to play with out some sort of tool, that would validate the game at client-side.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is an arms race in which the black hats far outnumber the white hats.  Even if there was a way to check, the likelihood is that the same folks who hacked the game would hack the verification to impersonate a non-hacked game.  *It's what they do...*  It can be a bummer though.  Is it more of an issue with this game because of unfair gameplay, or is your reasoning just ideological?

Comment: I dont care much for EA or Blizzard games being cracked, but I do think indie developers should be supported. Over the past years they have brought so much fresh air to this industry. I wouldn't want them to stop because of how hard it is to start in this market. It is just my way of showing support.